# Is there a reason for the web browsers to redirect to https when domain name ends with .dev?

Tags: web-browser

I had the following configuration.

An Apache VirtualHost record

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public
    ServerName test.dev

    <Directory /var/www/test/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This line in the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1        test.dev
```

And when I access the site with typing `http://test.dev` on Firefox. It used to work fine.

However recently when I try to access the site with the same URL, it keeps redirecting me to SSL (`https://test.dev`) for some reason.

Then I commented out both the VirtualHost record and host file record. But still the browser keeps redirecting it to SSL. So I thought it's a problem in Firefox. Then I did these:

- Changed Firefox's `browser.urlbar.autoFill` to `false` in `about:config`.
- Cleared the whole browser history related to that particular site.
- Restarted Firefox in safe mode.

But there was no difference.

I also checked in the `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` file in browser profile directory to find the site domain name listed there but it wasn't.

Finally I installed Chromium and checked (wish I did it before all the above Firefoxy things) and it gave me the same result.

So the both browsers redirects to SSL for no reason.

After a while I changed the domain name in `VirtualHost` record and in the host file to `test.d` and suddenly the site starts working normally.

So the conclusion is, when there is `.dev` extension in the domain name, it redirects to SSL.

I need to know why this is happening?

What sits between the browser and the `hosts` file so that I can check this?

This is not a huge problem on my side. But I would like to have the knowledge if someone willing to provide. Thanks..!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about elementary OS, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent Chrome (>= 63) from using https on `.dev` domain names. Google now owns the official `.dev` tld and has already stated that they will not remove this functionality. Firefox also does this.

The recommendation is to use another tld for development purposes, such as `.localhost` or `.test`. Personally, I use subdomains of [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me) as they don't require any special setup.

More information about this update can be found in [this article by Mattias Geniar](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information I got really confused when `.dev` suddenly got broken...!